# Cassandra Number Of Tokens Per Partition

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I've recently started learning Cassandra and while going through the Datastax docs on Nodesync 
[Nodesync-Doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/aboutNodesync.html)

came across this statement where it describers the token range of a segment.

> The token ranges can be no smaller than a single partition, so very large partitions can result in segments larger than the configured size.

The way I understood partitioning in Cassandra is that, it's like a single token denotes a single partition. There could be multiple rows for that particular token, but there wouldn't be multiple tokens per Cassandra partition. Did I get it wrong and if not could someone please explain what it's ment by token ranges per partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one partition == token. I think that confusion comes from the *segment* term that is used by NodeSync - one NodeSync segment may include multiple partitions, but it couldn't be smaller than partition.